# language support in android

Tags: android

I want to create an android application which requires Kannada language,the regional languauge of Karnataka,India.Could anyone let me know whether I could create my application based on that? Thanks

Comment: you can do this just make a banner in kannada.static instruction in kannada. but input language you cant be change its issue of protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this

**Step 1:** Download a kannada font .ttf file. (For example say
   brhknd.ttf).

**Step 2:** Now create a directory "fonts" in your assets folder in the
   android project.

**Step 3**: Now copy the brhknd.ttf file into assets/fonts
   folder in you Android project.

**Step 4:** Add these lines to your onCreate()

```
Typeface kannada = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/brhknd.ttf");
```

**Step 5:** Now provide this typeface to your TextView you want.

```
 textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipstext);
 textview.setTypeface(kannada);
 textview.setTextSize(20);
 textview.setText( "Jackson dsilva mangalore");
```

Comment: Hi,I am following the same steps. And I am able to display Tamil fonts but not Kannada fonts. I am targeting Android 4.0. Can you please tell me, where am I going wrong? or What font file you are using for Kannada?

Comment: Kannada fonts are not displaying in this way.