# How to set a different language to the ListContents in my ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have two simple ListViews:

```
public class SimpleListView extends Activity {
private ListView lv1 = null;
private ListView lv2 = null;
private String s1[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g","h","i"};
private String s2[] = {"j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o","p","q"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);         
    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list1);
    lv2 = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list2);

    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, s1));
    lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, s2));

}  

}
```

Here I want to list-contents i.e. s1 and s2 to be of different language instead of a,b,c..
How can I do that?

Thanks

#### EDIT:

According to [language support in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758454/language-support-in-android/6898595#6898595) I came to know that I can set different language to the TextViews.Now I want to set the language to the list-contents.

Comment: Didn't get what you want to exactly perform?

Comment: @PM - Paresh Mayani,let me ask you this one first.Is it possible for me to develop an application in any of the regional languages?

Comment: @PM - Paresh Mayani-Well in that case I want to list some of the countries in the contents my listview in the regional language.How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Well if you're asking how to find out what the active language on the device is look here [Get the current language in device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212320/get-the-current-language-in-device)
then fill your s1 and s2 according to the language

Answer (score 1):

You should use localized `strings.xml` files.

Your res/values folder contains a `strings.xml` file.

By creating additional values folders with a translated `strings.xml` file, you can cover all the regional languages you want.

Here are some examples:

- `res/values` (for English)
- `res/values-de` (for German)
- `res/values-zh` (for Chinese)
- `res/values-es` (for Spanish)
- `res/values-no` (for Norwegian)
- `res/values-da` (for Danish)

All the folder must contain a `strings.xml` file with the translated strings. If your original strings.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">English title</string>
</resources>
```

... then it could be like this for the German version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">German title</string>
</resources>
```

**Using string resources**

If you want to get a string from the strings resources, then here's how you do.

*In code:* `getString(R.strings.app_name) // returns "English title" for English users, "German title" for German users, etc.`

*In layout:* `@string/app_name`

**More info**

The Android developer site has an excellent guide on the subject here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html